# Creating Linked List of Nodes

Tags: c, linked-list, nodes

I want to write a main function that will create linked list of nodes with each one of them holding two int values in two fields in addition to the next field.( Make a struct node outside the main class.) The first int is a count of the node num. The other int is the next number in the Fibonacci sequence starting at 1. Continue adding nodes in the list until the value in the 2nd field in a new node exceeds the value in the 1st field * 1000.

As each node is being added, output the count onto one line. (Dont add the final node in the linked list.) It should basically print out the values from the 2nd field, in column, 5 per line.

The output should look something like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

1   1    2     3     5
8   13   21    34    55
89  144   233   377   610   
987 1597  2584  4181  6765
10946 17711
```

I know how to make the struct node and I know the fibonacci code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
  int x;
  int y;
  struct node * next;
} node_t;

int main()
{
  int first = 0, second = 1, nxt, c;
  int num = 0;


    for ( c = 1 ; c < 23 ; c++ )
      {
    if ( c <= 1 )
      nxt = c;
    else
      {
        nxt = first + second;
        first = second;
        second = nxt;
      }
    printf("%d\n", nxt);

      }

  return 0;
}
```

Need help with the node part basically.

Any help or guidance is much much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Creation of a node

A single node shall be created using dynamic memory allocation(malloc), see create_node()

Linked list creation

Requires one pointer to first item, another pointer to curr_item. The first item must be stored into first_node. After creating each item, it must be appended to the current item. curr_node must be updated to point last item. following code illustrates a sample linked list creation.

```
node_t *create_node(int nr, int fib );
int main()
{    
      node_t *first_node=NULL; /* First node */
      node_t *curr_node=NULL;  /* Current node */
      node_t *tmp_node=NULL;
      /* Creating a list of 20 items*/
      for(i=0;i<20;i++){
        if (first_node==NULL){
          curr_node=create_node(i,i*10);
          first_node=curr_node;
        }
        else{
          curr_node->next=create_node(i,i*10); /*appending to current */
          curr_node = curr_node->next;         /* make it as current */
        }
      }
      i=0;
      /* Traversing Linked list */
      for(tmp_node=first_node;tmp_node!=NULL;tmp_node=tmp_node->next){
         printf("%d --- %d\n",tmp_node->x, tmp_node->y);
         i++;
      }
    }
    node_t *create_node(int nr, int fib ){
        node_t *node;
        node = (node_t*) malloc(sizeof(node_t));
        node->x=nr;
        node->y=fib;
        node->next=NULL;
        return node;    

      }
```

Good resources are available on internet, do a google search "c linked list implementation"